# Chrome Extension webAudio API stops Windows power saving modes

Tags: javascript, hibernate, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, html5-audio

I have a problem with a chrome extension. The extension creates an audioContext which connects to a `<audio>` tag on a background page using the following code. On audio end `onClick()` the kill function is called.

When playing I see (expected) `[DRIVER] High Definition Audio Device (HDAUDIO\FUNC_01&VEN_111D&DEV_76D5&SUBSYS_1028040A&REV_1001\4&143c5ca7&0&0001)
An audio stream is currently in use.` when performing `powercfg -requests` on a windows system. However when calling the kill function, I still see the same driver in use message and the machine will not suspend/sleep/hibernate.

When inspecting the background page, the variables listed - all that are related to audio - are all undefined. The only cure I've found so far is to reload the background page - a superhack and I despise everything it stands for.

Anyone with similar experiences or a knowledge of the chrome webaudio API inner demons?

Point of note:
The variables are global in the context of the demo code. In the live code these are local scope.

Cheers, 
Phil.

```
function kill_audio_context(){
    capAudio.remove();
    capAudio = undefined;
    try{
        analyser.disconnect();
        source.disconnect();
        audioContext = undefined;
        source=undefined; 
        analyser=undefined;
    }catch(e){console.log(e)} 
    // No errors, except expected when no audio element exists (first load)

    // KILL IT WITH FIRE!!
    //chrome.runtime.reload();
}
function load_audio_context(){
    audioContext = new AudioContext();
    analyser = audioContext.createAnalyser();
    analyser.fftSize = 2048;
    source = audioContext.createMediaElementSource(capAudio);
    source.connect(analyser);
    analyser.connect(audioContext.destination);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call [`audioContext.close()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AudioContext/close) when you want to release the `AudioContext`.